# Problem in understanding an expectation

Tags: self-study, expected-value, integral

I was reading [this link](http://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/ir/bitstream/1840.16/5768/1/etd.pdf), where in page 41, the quantity
\begin{equation}
E\left\lbrace \left[ \int K(u)\sum_{i=1}^{n}W_{1i}(u)\{dN_{1i}(u)-\lambda(u)Y_{1i}(u)du\}\right] ^2\right\rbrace
\end{equation}
has been estimated as
\begin{align*}
1/n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[ \int \hat{K}(u) \sum_{i=1}^n W_{1i}(u)\{dN_{1i}(u)-\hat{\lambda}(u)Y_{1i}(u)du\}\right] ^2.\\
\end{align*}
Is it okay? It seems to me like the squared quantity is a constant, since it involves an integration over time point $u$ for all individuals $i$, and the estimated quantity should rather be 
\begin{align*}
1/n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[ \int \hat{K}(u)W_{1i}(u)\{dN_{1i}(u)-\hat{\lambda}(u)Y_{1i}(u)du\}\right] ^2.\\
\end{align*}
But I am not sure. Could anyone please explain which one is correct?